# Create setters for ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Stackers.
I guess this question is pretty forward, but how is it possible for me to create individual setters in ValidateUser?

Right now it is the constructor that sets them all at once, but I need to have individual setters like:

```
public void setUsername(String user){
    userName = user;
}
```

... and so forth.

This is my current ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ValidateUser> personer = new ArrayList<ValidateUser>();
public Users() {
    personer.add(new ValidateUser("admin", "asdf123", 0.8, "admin"));
    personer.add(new ValidateUser("jesper", "ukamm19", 2.5, "user"));
    personer.add(new ValidateUser("lars", "lol123", 1.5, "user"));
}
```

Comment: `public void addUser(ValidateUser user)`

Comment: @SteveKuo where do I put my parameters then?

Comment: You create ValidateUser just like you did above.   Just put that in the parameter of addUser(new ValidateUser(....))

Comment: `public void addUser(ValidateUser user) { personer.add(user); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this..

```
public class ValidateUser{
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private double rating;
    private String type;
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

then you can use like this..

```
    ValidateUser user = new ValidateUser();
    user.setUser("admin");
    user.setPass("*****");
    user.setRating(5.4);
    user.setType("admin");
    personer.add(user);
```

Comment: my question is the same; where to put the individual parameters?

Comment: But how does Java knows which parameter from the new ValidateUser("admin", "asdf123", 0.8, "admin")) to put where?

Comment: yeah it was the second block of code, that did the trick for me! Thanks! :)

Comment: Consider making all of `ValidateUser`'s fields final.

Comment: @SteveKuo i'm having some problems, when adding more "users". They seem to override each others informations. If not creating users1, users2 objects, how would be able to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is confusing, because you mention your `ArrayList`, but your actual question seems to be about the `ValidateUser` class.  If you want individual setters, you have to modify the `ValidateUser` class to accept those setters.  If you control that class, you can simply do this:

```
public class ValidateUser {       
   private String user;

   public void setUsername(String user) {
       this.user = user;
   }    
   // etc    
}
```